# This jQuery, Moment.js script won't display in SharePoint Online script editor web part, any ideas why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, momentjs, sharepoint-online

I set up a Script Editor Web Part in my SharePoint Online account.  The results show when I'm ***editing*** the page, but not when ***browsing*** the page.

Here's the script I'm using:

```
<h3>You got married: <span id="married"></span></h3>
<h3>Adam was born: <span id="adamBorn"></span></h3>   

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mysite.sharepoint.com/tech/Scripts/moment-with-langs.js">    </script>
<script>

  function setMoments(){
        var married = $('#married'),
            date = moment("1951-12-05", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
            update = function(){
                   married.html(date.fromNow());
            };
       update();

    var adamBorn = $('#adamBorn'),
        date = moment("1992-06-14", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
        update = function(){
                   adamBorn.html(date.fromNow());
                 };


    update();

  };

  _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setMoments");
</script>
```

I also tried the using document.ready, but the results still don't display when browsing the page.

Comment: Try to put _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setMoments"); on top of the script tag.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets no luck. Same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Incorrect**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mysite.sharepoint.com/tech/Scripts/moment-with-langs.js">    </script>
```

**Correct**

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://mysite.sharepoint.com/tech/Scripts/moment-with-langs.js">    </script>
```

*Apparently you have to specify the language :-)*

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to debug, like adding an `alert()` before `setMoments()` to make sure this part of the code is reached at some point?

Also your code can be simplified:

```
<script>
$('#married').html(moment("1951-12-05", "YYYY-MM-DD").fromNow());
$('#adamBorn').html(moment("1992-06-14", "YYYY-MM-DD").fromNow());
</script>
```

Because your script is after the both fields, then there is no need to use a `$(documen).ready` or `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames`.

Comment: I updated to use your script and the same behavior.  The results show when I'm editing the page, but not when browsing the page.  Thank you for the simplified code.